# How can I use a datapack to remove a block's default behavior?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to script custom behavior for a sponge in a datapack I'm writing, and I also want to remove the default "absorbing" behavior. If I were to type

```
/datapack disable vanilla
```

I noticed that sponges would no longer absorb water. I obviously want to keep vanilla enabled, but I'm wondering if it's possible to remove or overwrite the sponge's behavior specifically.

Comment: WTF? I didn't know sponges stopped absorbing water when the vanilla datapack is disabled. They shouldn't do that. Absorbing water is not handled via functions or tags or anything like that.

Comment: I thought the vanilla datapack just had loot tables, recipes, and structures, no functions. I wonder if anything else is controlled in the vanilla datapack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is handled by the "fluid tag" for water, located in a datapack at `minecraft/tags/fluids/water.json`. A sponge removes everything that gets added to this tag.

So no, you can not change just this one behaviour of sponges without changing many other properties of water.

Comment: can't he(sorry if you are a girl asker of the question) just add his own behavior pack where he removes the "fluid tag" from water and then sponge would have nothing to apply the "absorbing" behavior to?

Comment: It's not called "behaviour pack". And sure, they could do that, but then water would act like air.